# metamask fails to be enable on the ethjs examples

Tags: ethjs

I enabled the metamask by uncommenting the section regarding metamask on ethjs examples from Github but they were no connection and examples seem not been deployed. I am wondering if there is something extra that need to be added in order to connect with metamask. Examples work with uncommented section, meaning the metamask section was not uncommented, but once you enable metamask nothing work. Need help on this matter.

Comment: it would be helpfull if you include some code snipets in your question

Comment: Hello Badr, thank you. Here one of the ethjs examples on this link:https://github.com/ethjs/examples/blob/master/first-contract.html. I have ran the example, and it works well, but when I enable the metamask it did not show anything. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

By looking at the code mentioned in the comment I think you need to uncomment the following code :

```
/*
      // uncomment to enable MetaMask support:
      if (typeof window.web3 !== 'undefined' && typeof window.web3.currentProvider !== 'undefined') {
        eth.setProvider(window.web3.currentProvider);
      } else {
        eth.setProvider(provider); // set to TestRPC if not available
      }
      */
```

Comment: Dear Badr, I uncommented that section and it still not working. Did it work when you tried it?

Comment: try to inspect your code,using console.log( window.web3.currentProvider)

Comment: have a look also at https://github.com/MetaMask/metamask-extension/issues/2514

Comment: Hell Badr, I tried your suggestions but I still not been able to enable metamask. Please help